# Can a RESTful API return multiple ressources in one request?

Tags: rest, api, http, uri

I want to display events in calendar, but events come from multiple  ressources in the API. Is it a bad practice to do a single route that return multiple ressources in the payload to avoid calling multiple routes, front side?

For example, instead of calling

GET /users/42/availabilities?minDate=1999-01-01&maxDate=2001-01-01

```
[{
  startDate: '2000-01-01 00:00',
  endDate: '2000-01-01 01:00'
}]
```

GET /users/42/events?minDate=1999-01-01&maxDate=2001-01-01

```
[{
  type: 'project-presentation',
  startDate: '2000-01-01 00:00',
  endDate: '2000-01-01 01:00'
}]
```

Can I make a route that will return the result two ressources? Is it a good practice?

GET /users/42/calendar?minDate=1999-01-01&maxDate=2001-01-01

```
{
  availabilities: [{ // equivalent of GET /users/42/availabilities?minDate=1999-01-01&maxDate=2001-01-01
    startDate: '2000-01-01 00:00',
    endDate: '2000-01-01 01:00'
  }],
  events: [{ // equivalent of GET /users/42/events?minDate=1999-01-01&maxDate=2001-01-01
    type: 'project-presentation',
    startDate: '2000-01-01 00:00',
    endDate: '2000-01-01 01:00'
  }],
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR: yes, go right ahead; be aware that there are consequences.

Longer answer is something of a tangle.  The important thing to understand is that resources are 1:1 with resource identifiers.  The message body you get back in response to a `GET` request is a representation of *that* resource.

So if you start with

```
/A
/B
```

And you decide that for some use case that you need a coarser grain, you might introduce a new resource

```
/A-and-also-B
```

where the representation of `/A-and-also-B` is some projection of `/A` merged with some projection of `/B`.

Assuming that the media-type has the right sort of fragment semantics, you might even be able to work with

```
/A-and-also-B#A
/A-and-also-B#B
```

To get at the A and B parts of the combined representation.

HOWEVER - as far as a REST client is concerned, there is no equivalence between `/A` or `/B` and `/A-and-also-B`.  They are three *different* resources.  They are cached using different keys, and invalidating one of those keys has no impact on the others.

```
GET /A
GET /A-and-also-B
PUT /A <-- invalidates previously cached A, but does _not_ invalidate /A-and-also-B
```

In the future, rather than `/A-and-also-B`, you are more likely to see `/links-to-A-and-also-B`.  The pattern of linking to other resources is as old as the web (think html with images, or code-on-demand).  What has changed is the possibility of [Server Push](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP/2_Server_Push) -- that in response to your request for `/links-to-A-and-B`, the server might *also* push `/A` and `/B`.  So you get multiple resources returned at a single request.

Comment: Thanks a lot's for your response! Much more clear now :)